# How to stop function and run other after x seconds in Django?

Tags: python, django

So basically, I have a view that runs a function that is written in another file. Since I don't want the function running any longer than 25 seconds, is there any way for me to skip the function after it has run for 25 seconds and return the redirect reverse? Here is what my view looks like

```
def radio(request):
   song_search = request.POST.get('search').capitalize()

   request.session['song'] = song_search

   if models.Genre.objects.filter(Song=song_search):
       song_query_createobject(request)

   else:
       song_query_createobject(request)

       song_finder(request)

   return redirect(reverse('songresult'))
```

Comment: You should probably look into running the function asynchronously via something like celery. Can you share the function? Creating or finding an object shouldn't take so long?

Comment: The big function is the song_finder function and it doesn't search through a model. It's a scraper that's like 200 lines of code.